# How to implement Queue to functions call in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a button that call save function that call save function in the service.

```html
    <button (click)="save()">save</button>
```

```js
    save() {
     this.someService.save().subscribe(r => {
       console.log({ r });
     });
    }
```

I want each click on the button the action(the save method from the service) will insert to a queue.

After the current save method on the service is complete, then pull the next from queue and call again to save method from the service and so on until nothing in the queue.

I try something like this but I'm not sure why it's works only once..

*** a note: the `save` function in `SomeService` I can't change.**

```js
    save() {
     this.someService.addToQueue(true).subscribe(r => {
       console.log({ r });
     });
    }
```

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class SomeService {
  queue = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    this.queue.pipe(concatMap(a => this.save(a)));
  }

  addToQueue(saveAndExit) {
    this.queue.next(saveAndExit);

    return this.queue;
  }

  save(saveAndExit) {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        obs.next({ data: true });
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
}
```

[Demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9djcjr)

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Comment: ConcatMap fits  your use case

Comment: I try but it's doesn't work. why?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried

Comment: please look at the question.

Comment: Could you quickly create a stackblitz

Comment: try `return this.queue.pipe(concatMap(a => this.save(a)));` in your addToQueue

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2hv2jt Can you reproduce the issue over here

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `concatMap` here is that it does not subscribe to the next inner Observable until previous completes. If you complete it:

```
  save(saveAndExit) {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        obs.next({ data: true });
        obs.complete()
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
```

Your problem would be solved, but as you can not change that function, you need to manually complete it, with f.ex. `take(1)` or `first()`:

```
this.queue.pipe(concatMap(a => this.save(a).pipe(take(1)) ));
```

Comment: its not working because I getting the `{ r: true}` multiple times after I click on the save button. and its come after less 5 seconds that I defined in SetTimeout..

Comment: because you create a new subscription opon every click. Move `this.some.queue.subscribe` outside of the `save` method. In `constructor`  or `ngOnInit`

Comment: But I want when I click the save button it's should go to the service to save method. I can't do it any where else, just on the save click event. maybe another solution that fit to my cases?

Comment: When I click on the button I need to do subscribe. its simple this way. now the event should call a service that concat all the events and send back to subscribe. can we do that with rxjs?

Comment: Here  - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dg42vc?file=src/app/some.service.ts Is that what you want?

Comment: The problem is if I had a component that use this service then it will trigger subscribe event to another component that I don't need.

Comment: you are subscribing in component, not service. Sorry I dont understand whats your problem